# Resource Management in Node.js

Tags: node.js, resources

I want to test my custom server sent sample request and the ram usage of server is increased. Then pause the requests but ram usage is't free or decrease! Note that we remove variable after each request but condition did not change.
For test i send 60 request in second and after 1 minute, 1.2G of ram is used!

Comment: about 4 years have passed and still without answer!